# How to swap Caps with Left Control and change layouts using Caps Lock+Swith (grp:shift_caps_switch)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, swap, xmodmap, xkb

I already tried a lot of methods for changing this and none of those worked. I used xmodmap and setxkbkey but it both ways there's always problem with setting it. However, using those methods don't work correcly and using them separateley also don't work.

I want to:

- swap "Caps Lock" with "Left Control";
- don't use "Caps Lock" as "Caps Lock" key (no toggle to uppercase);
- switch layouts with "Caps Lock" (mapped to "Left Control") to first layout and "Shift+Caps Lock" (again, "Caps Lock" should be mapped to "Left Control") to second.

Is there a way to do it correctly?

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04. Such methods don't work:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option '' -option grp:shift_caps_switch -option ctrl:swapcaps
```